.NET Process.OutputDataReceived still receiving data after unsubscribe the Event Handler and Kill the Process
Please. I need to read data from a process asynchronously because sometimes data is received indefinitely and cannot be read synchronously. When I have read enough characters, I unsubscribe from the event handlers and kill the process, returnig the value However, the data is still received in OutputDataReceived and ErrorDataReceived, even when the program has already exited the GetYTTitle() function. How can I stop receiving these data in the event handlers?
Here is the function sample:
public static string GetYTTitle(string link)
        {
            //link example: 
            //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QxwYWYzEis&list=RDEMF3TMXnvKDsn8vLgAp5nmdA&index=9
            string standard_output = "";
            int n = 0;
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\youtube-dl\yt-dlp.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = " --get-title " + link;
            p.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e != null)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine(" error Ouput Data ");
                  Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
                }
            };

            p.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e != null)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("Datos de Standard Ouput: ");
                  Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
                  standard_output += e.Data;
                  if (standard_output.Length > 100)
                  {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enough charactes gotten");
                        p.ErrorDataReceived -=  (s, e)=> { };
                        p.OutputDataReceived -= (s, e) => { };
                        p.Kill();
                  }
                }
            };

            p.Exited += (s, e) =>
            { 
                 Console.WriteLine("Process finished.");
                 p.ErrorDataReceived -= (s, e) => { };
                 p.OutputDataReceived -= (s, e) => { };
                 p.Kill();
            };

            p.Start();
            p.BeginErrorReadLine();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            while (!p.HasExited)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                n = n+1; ;
                Console.WriteLine(n + " seconds elapsed of " +40);
                Console.ResetColor();
                if (n > 39)
                {
                    p.ErrorDataReceived -= (s, e) => { };
                    p.OutputDataReceived -= (s, e) => { };
                    p.Kill();
                    return standard_output;        
                }
            }
            return standard_output;
        }


Thank You.
I have unsubscribed from the event handlers and killed the process before exiting the function. However, the data is still received in OutputDataReceived and ErrorDataReceived, even when the program has already exited the GetYTTitle() function. How can I stop receiving these interminable data in the event handlers?

You're not actually unsubscribing from the event handlers here, you are trying to unsubscribe a different delegate. You can use the example here to do it easily.

Also, the Process object should be disposed. Consider using using Process p = new Process();

Thank you DavidG I have finally found the way the unsubscribe using:                         p.CancelOutputRead();
